# Sort file/folder output in Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, text-processing, sort

I have output like this (alphanumerical):

```
bash /etc/file
bash /etc/filenew
bash /etc/skel/
bash /etc/skel/file
bash /etc/skel/filenew
bash /etc/skel/new/backups/
bash /etc/skel/new/file
bash /etc/skel/old/backups/
bash /etc/skel/old/file
bash /usr/
bash /usr/bin/
bash /usr/bin/file
bash /usr/sbin/
bash /usr/sbin/file.sbin
```

Which I need to sort (the output itself) to show directories first, as per:

```
bash /etc/skel/
bash /etc/skel/new/backups/
bash /etc/skel/new/file
bash /etc/skel/old/backups/
bash /etc/skel/old/file
bash /etc/skel/file
bash /etc/skel/filenew
bash /etc/file
bash /etc/filenew
bash /usr/
bash /usr/bin/
bash /usr/bin/file
bash /usr/sbin/
bash /usr/sbin/file.sbin
```

Comment: Even with directories first, why does `/etc/bash.bashrc` come after `/etc/skel/.bash_logout`?

Comment: @muru I want to make the subdirectories come before the files too.

Comment: `/etc/skel/bash.logout` is still a file.

Comment: @muru yes, but it's in the subdirectory `skel/`

Comment: How do generate the output? Could you use `find -depth` for your listing?

Comment: @Fiximan well, the output is generated by a separate command, which unfortunately doesn't support that (or any other alternative) sorting. That's why I need to sort the output itself.

Comment: Then, does `/a/b/c/d` come before or after `/a/b/d`?

Comment: @muru, yes, before. Just like `/a/b/d/c` should come before `/a/b/c`.

Comment: @muru that's removed.

Comment: Thanks, Det, but you shouldn't have gone for 100. That takes away your commenting privileges. :/

Comment: @muru Don't worry about it, mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following command comes close:

```
sed -r 's:([^/]*/):d\1:g; s:([^/]+)$:f\1:' foo.txt |
  sort |
  sed -r 's:/f:/:; s:d([^/]*/):\1:g'
```

What does it do? The first `sed` command adds a `d` to the beginning of every directory (by looking for strings that end with a `/`), and an `f` to files - those that don't end with `/`. Then we apply `sort` - and since `d` sorts before `f`, directories get sorted first. The second `sed` undoes the first one.

For the example input:

```
$ sed -r 's:([^/]*/):d\1:g; s:([^/]+)$:f\1:' foo.txt |
 sort |
 sed -r 's:/f:/:; s:d([^/]*/):\1:g'
bash /etc/skel/
bash /etc/skel/new/backups/
bash /etc/skel/new/file
bash /etc/skel/old/backups/
bash /etc/skel/old/file
bash /etc/skel/file
bash /etc/skel/filenew
bash /etc/file
bash /etc/filenew
bash /usr/
bash /usr/bin/
bash /usr/bin/file
bash /usr/sbin/
bash /usr/sbin/file.sbin
```

Comment: if `d` precedes `f`, how come `/usr/` is before `/etc/file` in your output?

Comment: Oh sorry, I read your input as output. Where is the latter? Nevertheless I think he wants to still keep all `/etc/` before all `/usr/` entries and then have files last for the subdirs only

Comment: Oh now I get you, but still: if the line was `d bash /usr/` and the other one `f bash /etc/file` how come that `/usr/` is after  `/etc/file`? shouldn't all files be after all dirs?

Comment: @Fiximan the replacement is *global* - the line would be like `dbash /dusr/`, `dbash /detc/ffile`, etc.

Comment: Very clever , very clever

Comment: The final command I ended up using is `sed -r 's:([^/]*/):d\1:g;s:([^/]+)$:f\1:' foo.txt | sort | sed -r 's:d([^/]*/):\1:g' | sed -r 's:f([^/]):\1:g' | sort -n -k6 -t/`. `sed -r 's:f([^/]):\1:g'` to turn non-f* files back and `sort -n -k6 -t/` to have `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/`come before `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/`. I'll have you take **+100 points** for this answer in 2 days, and you won't be able to stop me.

Comment: @Det Ah, yes, I was using a more complex Perl command that I translated to `sed`. Forgot about the `f` prefix. Sorry about that.

Comment: Was the `perl` one shorter?

Comment: @Det not by much. I used lookaheads originally before realising I could do without them.  I fixed the command in the post. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Det to get `16x16` come before `128x128`, try `sort -V` in the middle `sort`.

Comment: @muru that also makes uppercase names come before lowercase, even though my `LC_COLLATE` is `en_US.UTF-8`. By the way, you left a `;s:` in the end of the upper `sed` command, which is also the only place where there's a space separating the two `sed`'s. Maybe that's just me, but it's easier for my eyes to have at least a space in them all.

Comment: @Det I removed that traling `;s:`.

Comment: @muru Thank you. If I could just nag about the lower `sed .. foo.txt` command, which is the last one without the space.

Comment: Take that[.](http://example.com)